# Is it enough to just use induction?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I have a function $f$ that I believe satisfies the following formula for all $n$ and for $0\leq m \leq n+1$ $$(2m^2+1)^{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{m}f(n,m-i)$$ I don't think it is relevant to my question to provide any other details. Is is enough to do a simple induction on $n$?

Comment: You will need to show that it holds for all $m$ with $0 \leq m \leq n + 1$ at each step, but yes, that should work in principle.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Do be careful to get the "for all relevant  $m$" part right in you argument.

Comment: How do I go about being careful with it? I actually only realised the restriction on $m$ after the proof was 'finished' due to the function $f$ only being valid for said $m$.

Comment: "Is is enough to do a simple induction on n?" - Well, did you try it and did it work? It sort of depends what $f$ is.

Comment: It seems to work but I am not certain its a complete proof

Comment: As said: it should work in principle. Still doubts? Then provide function $f$ so that it can be checked.